# Swift: how to create FDWaveformview Dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I want to show wave of multiple audios in scrollview using swift4 and xcode 9. I am using cocoapos library FDWaveFormView for showing wave of audio file. For this I have to create fdwaveformview dynamically. Fdwaveformview works fine if I create this in story board. But it shows an error when create dynamically in swift class.

Code:

```
for index in selectedAudios {

  audioQueue.append(AVPlayerItem(url: index as! URL))
  print("aduio url: \(index)")

  let waveForm = FDWaveformView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 150)) // error
  audio_scroll_view.addSubview(waveForm!)
}
```

**Screen Shot Of Error**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Error:** `FDWaveformView` initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 100)
let waveform = FDWaveformView()
waveform.frame = frame
audio_scroll_view.addSubview(waveform)
```